# How can I run a function in the background with neovim

Tags: neovim

Simple question really, how can I run a custom function in a seperate thread with nvim?

Comment: What do you mean by custom function? nvim function like `echo`, `sort` and so on? Or some external program?

Comment: A regular funtion defined in .vimrc

Comment: By thread you mean a real separate thread or executing it on a nvim event loop in async way will be enough?